# I can't install pip package installer

Tags: python, django, pip

[image: me]

The pip python installer is telling me that pip was already installed and it shows the below error:

```
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/00/b6/9cfa56b4081ad13874b0c6f96af8ce16cfbc1cb06bedf8e9164ce5551ec1/pip-19.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 19.3.1
    Uninstalling pip-19.3.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-19.3.1
[33m  WARNING: The scripts pip.exe, pip3.8.exe and pip3.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\ABUBAKAR SADIQ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.[0m
Successfully installed pip-19.3.1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PIP 10.0.1 - Warning "Consider adding this directory to PATH or..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49966547/pip-10-0-1-warning-consider-adding-this-directory-to-path-or)

Comment: It seems to have worked. So, what problem are you actually having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have installed pip package, but Windows has no idea where is that package. You need to add the directory to the Windows's PATH variable.

In your command line execute:

```
setx path "%path%;C:\Users\ABUBAKAR SADIQ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts"
```