# TypeError: Workbook.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'options'

Tags: python, openpyxl, system-administration

I am getting this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Python310\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 1921, in **call**
> return self.func(*args)   File "C:\Users\achille.gouttard\Documents\synergie\11_16_2021\app.py", line
> 861, in selectItem
> self.find_match(1)   File "C:\Users\achille.gouttard\Documents\synergie\11_16_2021\app.py", line
> 673, in find_match
> with ExcelWriter(path, engine="openpyxl",   File "C:\Users\achille.gouttard\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pandas\io\excel_openpyxl.py",
> line 72, in **init**
> self.book = Workbook(**engine_kwargs) TypeError: Workbook.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'options'

from this line of code:

```
 with ExcelWriter(path, engine="openpyxl",
            engine_kwargs={'options': {'strings_to_formulas': False, "strings_to_urls": False}}) as writer:
```

It used to work just fine but someone messed up with my Python installation and when I tried to reinstall everything I came across this error.

Note that when I installed the packages I had this warning:

> WARNING: The script styleframe.exe is installed in
> 'C:\Users\achille.gouttard\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Scripts'
> which is not on PATH.   Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if
> you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.

Can't find anything related to this issue so if you've got any ideas they are welcomed.

Comment: To solve your second problem with warning you need to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51165784/17845381) answer

Answer (score 2):

It is because engine `openpyxl` does not support engine kwargs.
You need to change the `engine` parametr (for example `'xlsxwriter'` works perfect).

```py
with pd.ExcelWriter(name, engine='xlsxwriter', engine_kwargs={'options': {'strings_to_numbers': True}}) as writer:
    stuff()
```

Also be note that if you do not have `xlsxwriter` library you should install it manually.

If there are no engine arg passed, it chooses engine automaticly.